# How to capture standard output of a shell command in elisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, stdout, capture

I want to run a shell command within Emacs and capture the full output to a variable. Is there a way to do this? For example, I would like to be able to set `hello-string` to `"hello"` in the following manner:

```
(setq hello-string (capture-stdout-of-shell-command "/bin/echo hello"))
```

Does the function `capture-stdout-of-shell-command` exist, and if so what is its real name?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Does [`shell-command-to-string`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Synchronous-Processes.html#index-shell_002dcommand_002dto_002dstring) meet your purpose?

For example:

```
(shell-command-to-string "/bin/echo hello")
```

Comment: Note that `shell-command-to-string` captures both `stdout` _and_ `stderr`. Luckily we can just pipe the stderr to /dev/null: `(shell-command-to-string "/bin/echo hello 2>/dev/null")`

Answer (score 27):

I have a suggestion to made that extends Ise Wisteria's answer. Try using something like this:

```
(setq my_shell_output
  (substring 
    (shell-command-to-string "/bin/echo hello") 
   0 -1))
```

This should set the string `"hello"` as the value of `my_shell_output`, but cleanly. Using `(substring)` eliminates the trailing `\n` that tends to occur when emacs calls out to a shell command. It bothers me in emacs running on Windows, and probably occurs on other platforms as well.

Comment: I've noticed emacs doing that on both Mac OS X and on Linux, so it's not just NTEmacs.

Comment: `(defun my-shell-command-to-string (&rest cmd)
         (replace-regexp-in-string "\r?\n$" "" (shell-command-to-string (mapconcat 'identity cmd " "))))`

Comment: @spacebat You want `\\'` in there, not `$`.

Comment: `echo hello` is `hello\n`.

Comment: In linux/osx, you can use ```-n``` to stop outputting the trailing newline., e.g. ```echo -n hello```

Comment: Doesn't work when combined with `(shell-command-to-string "/bin/echo hello 2>/dev/null")` per Yorick's comment above. Any tips for handling potentially empty strings?